# C# - Move objects in console application with different speed

Tags: c#, object, console, move

I am studying C# at the moment and I had an exam recently. I had to create a console game that has moving objects. I pretty much managed to do everything that was required, except I couldn't think out a way how to make each game object to move at different speed (actually there are only two moving objects, floors and the character), one of the tasks was to make powerups that increase either the character speed or the floors speed.... I couldn't think out a way how to modify their speed separately.. I am currently trying to finish the game but I cna't get my thoughts around this, my "endgame" is to have two variables charSpeed and floorSpeed... Could anyone explain to me how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

My code - http://pastebin.com/TkPd37xD - it's currently a mess, I just want to figure out what is the logic behind what I want to do. A "general solution", here I have only 2 objects, what if I want to change the speed of 10 objects?

P.S. No Classes, I can go up to Structs, I have not worked with Classes yet.
P.S.S. I take any kind of advices or criticizm about my code, so anything is appreciated since I am still learning, but my main concern at the moment is how to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: Post your code,otherwise we have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: My code is currently a mess I haven't extracted it in methods (or commented it) but here it is - http://pastebin.com/TkPd37xD , I am simply looking for the basic logic behind what I want to do, if you have two moving objects in a console application and you want them to move with different speed how would you normally do it...

Comment: Add a `Speed` property to each object (Or make a parent class with that property), make the default say 10 (which is normal movement). When moving things, move them multiplied by the speed. To move faster, increase the objects speed above 10, to slow down reduce speed below 10.

Comment: How would I use the Speed property individually for each object, my speed currently is determined by a Thread.Sleep(xx), row number 156..

Comment: The `Thread.Sleep` is theoretically your redraw speed (how long to wait until you process the next redraw with changes). But inside your code you move everything by x amount up/down/left/right. Hook that x into your speed and you have differential speed for floor/player.

Comment: If what you are suggesting is that when I click left arrow for example instead of moving "1 box" to the left I move 4 boxes to the left and this being is my speed increase, that is not an actual speed increase and it may cause a lot of bugs. For example if my holes are exactly 3 elements long I may not be able to go through them cuz I will always "jump above them" with that step, or the other thing that I won't be able to do at times is to get to the far left or far right of the playfield since I have to add another check if I am going out of the array...

Comment: What I really want to do is for example, I move the floors every 100 milliseconds but I can move my character once every 20 milliseconds, but I want to increment my step by 1 not by 5, so for every row generated I can move 5 times... hmmm now that I think about it, what if I put 50 ms for row generation and 10 for character that will total up to 100 again and before it generates a new row it will let me move 5 times, would this work?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Timer for each different levep speed.
The callback of the timer would execute the logic of the movement.

This will certainly required a refactoring of your code ;)

Comment: I know that one of the guys did something like that, could you explain how this works? I have never seen it

Comment: Have a look to : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I'm gonna need more than that, what is the logic behind implementing the timers in my current situation (or any other game that requires similar control)?
What am I ultimately trying to do with the Timer?